# Java XMLUnit not properly ignoring child order when comparing

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I am trying to use Java XMLUnit to check if these two XML's are the same, ignoring order. I have tried using the Diff approach as well as using NodeMatcher but neither worked. I have tried a variety of ElementQualifiers as well. What am I missing here?

These are the two XMLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <entry>
    <key>foo</key>
    <value>global</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>my_boolean</key>
    <value>false</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>my_number</key>
    <value>0</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>my_json</key>
    <value>[]</value>
  </entry>
</test>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <entry>
    <key>my_json</key>
    <value>[]</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>foo</key>
    <value>global</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>my_boolean</key>
    <value>false</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>my_number</key>
    <value>0</value>
  </entry>
</test>
```

Here are the code snippets I have tried:

```
XmlAssert.assertThat(actualXmlString)
    .and(expectedXmlString)
    .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .ignoreChildNodesOrder()
    // .ignoreWhitespace()
    .normalizeWhitespace()
    .areSimilar();

Diff diff = new Diff(actualXmlString, expectedXmlString);
diff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndTextQualifier());
assertXMLEqual(diff, true);
```

Comment: There is a `setIgnoreAttributeOrder` but for elements there would be needed a structural nested comparison (deep compare). I think you should do that yourself with a common subexpression mapping.

Comment: @JoopEggen Can you explain what you mean by common subexpression mapping? Do you mean there is some custom mapping library matcher or like Java string hacking?

Comment: Not that I know, of. You can do the equality test of elements after loading in java; probably maps with JPA or such. `Maps.equals` is then all you need in this case.